# Catel: MVVM how to get selected value from a listview and save it to a variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

Hi all I have a list view which is filled by an ObservableCollection. Now I want to get the value of the selected item from the list and store it. How I can achieve this?

This is my ViewModel:

```
  public StopViewModel(IGrtrService grtrService)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => grtrService);
        _grtrService = grtrService;

        AllStops = _grtrService.LoadStop();
        Stop_Line = _grtrService.LoadLines();

        SearchCollection = new Command(OnSearchPressed);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Stop> AllStopsCollection // Must be property or DP to be bound!
    {

        get { return AllStops; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, AllStops)) return;
            AllStops = value;               
        }
    }       

    public Grtr Grtr
    {
        get { return GetValue<Grtr>(GrtrProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GrtrProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData GrtrProperty = RegisterProperty("Grtr", typeof(Grtr));   

}
```

And in the XAML file I have the following code:

```
<catel:StackGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <catel:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />       
    </catel:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>

    <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Azure">
        <ToolBar>
            <TextBox Width="150" Text="{Binding Path=SearchValue}" />
            <Button Content="Search" Command="{Binding SearchCollection}" />
            <Button Content="Pass Object" Command="{Binding SearchCollection}" />
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllStopsCollection}"   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedStop}" />  

</catel:StackGrid>
```

Comment: hm, and where is a "SelectedStop" property of your ViewModel?

Comment: thats the problem I don't know how to do this I know how to make the property but I don't know to use it and assign the selected value to it.

Comment: actually you just need to create a property
    public Stop SelectedStop {
    get { return _selectedStop; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectedStop)) return;
            _selectedStop= value;               
        }}

Make sure that you implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and thet your property is raising "OnPropertyChanged" when  it's changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Catel, it will automatically take care of change notifications for your. Just define this property:

```
public Stop SelectedStop
{
    get { return GetValue<Stop>(SelectedStopProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedStopProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly PropertyData SelectedStopProperty = RegisterProperty("SelectedStop", typeof(Stop));
```

It will be set to the value.

**Pro tip**: if you use [Catel.Fody](http://catelproject.com/tools/catel-fody/), you can write this:

```
public Stop SelectedStop { get; set; }
```

and it will automatically be converted to the final Catel property as written above.

Comment: Omg thanks a million. But if I use this method do I have to set the binding in the XAML to: SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedStop, Mode=twoWay}"

Comment: To be sure: yes. Pro-answer: you have to check out the default binding mode (which you can customize in WPF) to check whether it is really required.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from comments you just can't figure out how to bind list's selected item to property. So first of all you need to create coresponding property in your view model:

```
    public Stop SelectedStop
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedStop;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _selectedStop)) return;
            _selectedStop = value;
        }
    }
```

Make sure that you implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and thet your property is raising "OnPropertyChanged" when it's changed.
And for the list box you should set:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllStopsCollection}"   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedStop, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel :

```
private stop _selectedStop;

public Stop SelectedStop
{
  get
  { 
    return _selectedStop;
  }
  set
  { 
  if (_selectedStop!= value)
     _selectedStop = value;
  OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStop"); //U should implement this method using INotifyPropertyChanged
  }
}
```

In your Window (XAML) , set the Binding's mode to TwoWay :

```
 <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllStopsCollection}"   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedStop, Mode=twoWay}" />
```